# Calendar App: How to sync moved items?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, core-data, calendar, synchronization

I am trying to build a calendar app with same set of syncing feature of [Google Calendar](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-calendar/id909319292?mt=8) and [Sunrise app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sunrise-calendar-for-google/id599114150?mt=8)

How to tackle moved events or deleted events ? For example: For a month API call I received 100 event ids and I stored it locally. Next time I should send MAX_ last_modified event value to fetch new/updated records. But using last_modified value will not solve problem for moved events.

And right now I am bound to fetch all events in a month everytime. This is an inefficient idea and I should not fetch already synced items everytime.

Let me know how to solve this issue ?
Server guys are also welcome here because current backend architecture is designed by rails team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider two scenarios:

- If LastModified not available  - then fetch all items
- If lastModified available - then it should return change sets with
  deleted items